async await unexpected error in playground
I have this code in playground for iOS, XCode v15.3:
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

func fetchWeatherHistory() async -> [Double] {
    (1...100).map { _ in Double.random(in: -10...30) }
}

func calculateAverageTemperature(for records: [Double]) async -> Double {
    let total = records.reduce(0, +)
    let average = total / Double(records.count)
    return average
}

func upload(result: Double) async -> String {
    "OKet"
}

func processWeather() async throws {
    var records = await fetchWeatherHistory()
    var average = await calculateAverageTemperature(for: records)
    var response = await upload(result: average)
    print("Server response: \(response)")
    return
}

do {
    try await processWeather()
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

I am getting this output (along with the error:
Server response: OKet
Playground execution failed:

error: execution stopped with unexpected state.
error: Execution was interrupted.
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

what is the error about, do you know? And how to fix it?

Why would the playground keep running long enough for your code to finish? And are you really allowed to say await in the middle of nowhere like that? I expect to see a Task at the top of the async chain. — Really, if I were you I wouldn't try to use async/await in a playground at all.

You need to tell Playgrounds that you are doing asynchronous work by setting needsIndefiniteExecution to true and calling finishExecution when you are done.

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
do {
    try await processWeather()
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()


this worked beautifully.
